# Text out of screen when small resolution

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having some issues with not being able to see all text on all my pages in a new wordpress website.

If I'm using a screen resolution smaller than 1920x1080p then the text wont fit on the page. I had a guy try fix it, but it didn't work.

You can see the issue here: http://holtumdata.dk/mission/

(Remember it's only on small resolutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you have defined a fixed width on a container div

```
.container {
width: 1700px;
}
```

---

doc on [Media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

Comment: If I remove the defined width, will it then be scaleable?
Or do I have to change further in the CSS afterwards?

EDIT: The issue is, if I remove the container, then the text is located in the middle of the screen, where it's supposed to be to the left, in all resolutions.

Comment: You could use a media query here to change the css when the screen becomes smaller

Comment: If I should use a media query, how would the code then look?
And would I have to make one for each type of resolution?

Comment: No one query is sufficient, just change it whenever the screen becomes to small. But for what I can see the site is already fixed? I've added a link with documentation for media queries

Comment: The site is fixed for smaller screens now, but not for bigger.
After i Removed the fixed width in the container div, then the text is located too far from the left on bigger resolutions.

Comment: If it's possible to make it scaleable, so it will fit any resolution, that would be amazing.

And with fitting any resolution, I mean where the text is located to the left of the page, in line with the logo on top.

Comment: the text is in the middle now because of this code: .container {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;}

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {width:100%;}
}
//this media query is alredy in your bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a class `.container` that has a fixed width.

```
.container {
    width: 1700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that your `container` has:

```
.container {
   width: 1700px;
}
```

Remove it and use percentages instead.

Comment: Tried removing it, issue is the text is in the middel of the window now: http://holtumdata.dk/mission/